# Keep Session Angularjs Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, authentication

I'm using the [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955770/jason) project that you can find at this [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) in my project.

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4 with WildFly 10 with Java 8 and SQL Server 2014. I can get the login correction, but when I refresh the page the same does not hold the session.

What could be happening? Besides the adaptations I have to do in 'user.service.js', do I have to change anything else to be able to keep the session?

My code user.service.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {};

        //service.GetAll = GetAll;
        //service.GetById = GetById;
        service.GetByUsername = GetByUsername;
        service.Create = Create;
        //service.Update = Update;
        //service.Delete = Delete;

        return service;

        //function GetAll() {
        //    return $http.get('rest/usuarios/login/').then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting all users'));
        //}

        //function GetById(id) {
        //    return $http.get('rest/usuarios/login/' + id).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by id'));
        //}

        function GetByUsername(usermatricula, usersenha) {
            return $http.post('rest/usuarios/login/' + usermatricula + '/' + usersenha).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by username'));
        }

        function Create(user) {
            return $http.post('rest/usuarios/', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
        }

        //function Update(user) {
        //    return $http.put('rest/usuarios/login/' + user.id, user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error updating user'));
        //}

        //function Delete(id) {
        //    return $http.delete('rest/usuarios/login/' + id).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error deleting user'));
        //}

        // private functions

        function handleSuccess(res) {
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;
        }

        function handleError(error) {
            return function () {
                return { success: false, message: error };
            };
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Where do you save user session in your script ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye I'll inform you that I'm new AngularJS, HTML5, JavaScript, Java ..

I do not think I'm saving anywhere. What I did was simply place the files and adapt the 'rest'. What do you suggest I do? What should I do in my code? Where should I put it?

Something like Jason did at 'user.service.local-storage.js'?

`// private functions function getUsers() {
if(!localStorage.users){          localStorage.users = JSON.stringify([]);}
return JSON.parse(localStorage.users);
        }
        function setUsers(users) {
            localStorage.users = JSON.stringify(users);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can store user data in localStorage when you get response from request as below

```
function handleSuccess(res) {
    console.log(res.data);
    // Put the object into storage
    localStorage.setItem('userSession', JSON.stringify(res.data));
    return res.data;
}
```

To check if a session exists you can do

```
// If an object named userSession exists in the local storage
if(localStorage.getItem('userSession')){
    // Retrieve the object from storage
    var userSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSession'));
}
```

And then check data in userSession

Comment: My code looks like this:`function handleSuccess(res) {console.log(res.data);localStorage.setItem('userSession', JSON.stringify(res.data));if(localStorage.getItem('userSession')){var userSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSession'));}return res.data;}`Is correct? Well, that did not work.I'm trying to debug, and by debug the same loses the information in after passing this line `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;` in the app.js file.You can see it in Github.

Comment: You have to put this `if(localStorage.getItem('userSessi‌​on')){var userSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSession'));}return res.data;}` where you want to check if the user is logged. Not after saving the session

Comment: Sorry, so I do not know where to put it. :(

Can you please edit the answer with the complete code, indicating what I have to change and where to put it? I've tried everything here, but so far nothing ...

When you say "where do you want to check if the user is logged", for me it was that part `function handleSuccess (res)`. I'm lost.

Comment: What is the function where you send user connexion ? handleSuccess ?

Comment: As I said in the initial post, I grabbed the file [user.service.js](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/blob/master/app-services/user.service.js) and changed only the `post` path. I think that's the way it is.

Comment: Can you still help me? Or maybe you can tell me another way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried my answer ? What did you get with it ?

Comment: I put it, even then I can not keep the session. Data has been saved to 'userSession'. But I could not recover to keep the session. Maybe I put the code in the wrong part. So tell me like this: "Put 'this code X' after 'this code Y'. ". Sorry for something, but I'm using Google Translate, so something may be meaningless, both for me and for you. :(

Comment: Okay create a fiddle with your code to let me see what's wrong

Comment: I created it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGrE0xfPeEYysvPNn3uu?p=preview). If you want anything else let me know. Some things are more like the original, but I believe that is not a problem. But if I need to, I'll take it back.

Comment: Okay try to put this `localStorage.setItem('userSession', JSON.stringify(res.data));` in your loginController before `$location.path('/professor');` and then you have to check if userSession exist in the controller that controlle your view /professor

Comment: Hi ... I updated the [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGrE0xfPeEYysvPNn3uu?p=preview). As for "res.data" you would have to change to "$ scope.teste.data", since it does not recognize "res.data". It still did not work, but .. how should I do this check in the "teacher" controller? You can do code for me :)